# How to get object from custom key type from map in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a custom class called `Foo`:

```
class Foo {
    constructor(public v: any) {
    }
}
```

And I have a map where `Foo` is my Key:

```
const map = new Map<Foo, string>();
```

AFAIK TypeScript doesn't have comparision overloading. How can I make sure that getting the key works properly?

```
const foo = new Foo(1234);
map.get(foo);
```

Here is the entire code:

```
class Foo {
    constructor(public v: any) {

    }
}

const map = new Map<Foo, string>();


const foo = new Foo(1234);
map.set(foo, "HELLO WORLD");

const foo2 = new Foo(1234);
console.log(map.get(foo2)); // DOESN'T work

console.log(map.get(foo)); // DOES work of course
```

You can find my problem here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ0PWPAdhALgE4Cuw+8hAFAA7EBGIAlsNAG4Bc0YOAngJQpU6TAF9UYodjz5oAWzDVoAXmg4ApgHdoAWQUAeBPAA00AoUY4A5gD5KfANxDUUgtABmiZas1xElAIwATADMACwOqPLUAHQQaviUHsbQAEQAEgCiADJZAPLQAOq5AEpZACIpEZK4rkmBXupahgEh4Y4u8CBq0SDwlpRR0ZbxiYiBfA7QAPRT0AAm8GoQOADkMhoUANZOHV09fQMKQyNJE-bTs2W5GQDK0BuE26hAA

Comment: you didnt set `foo2` on `map` or am I missing the point...

Comment: Thats the point. Both objects are same in value and therefore equal for my usecase

Comment: well `{} !== {}` in js, thats why, right?

Comment: Correct but thats not the end. If there would be no workarounds any `Array.find()` function would loose its purpose. Thats why such function has a custom "find" callback function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have isn't related to TypeScript, but rather JavaScript not having referential transparency. Therefore comparison like this `new Foo(123) === new Foo(123)` is always falsy.

**Solution**

The JavaScript's `Map` has a rather limited api. If you want to find specific entry using custom comparison function (in this case comparing by value), I'd suggest using `.entries()` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries) to get all the entries from the `Map` in form of an array of tuples `[key, value][]`. You can then find there whatever entry you want using `Array.find()`. The `Map` itself doesn't have any such method.

However, even better approach would be to rethink your data structure. Considering the limitations of the `Map` it would be better to have a primitive data type as a key in the `Map`. Since I don't know the specifics of your case I can only offer this general suggestion.